# Ionic App is not working in android device

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have created a app for getting results from OMDB to show ratings. It is working fine in browser when I am using `ionic serve` and also when I am using `ionic cordova emulate browser` (For android device). But the issue is when I am converting it to the android app (Via `ionic capacitor add android`, `ionic capacitor copy android`) and checking in my android device then it is not working there.

My device has installed latest version of android version with latest MIUI version.

TIA.

I have tried to find the solution but there is no solution found to me for this.

I am using HTTP call for mobile device and HTTPClient call for web browser. I am doing it in my localhost.

I expect that if it is working with cordova emulate browser then it must be working with android device

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "not working". Does the splash screen show? Are you getting any errors or just the "white screen of death"? Also have you used the Chrome Inspector to check for any errors inside your WebView?

Comment: @andypotato, When I am typing any movie name it is not showing me results. Whereas in browser (cordova emulator) it is showing proper result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

9 times out of ten this is because you haven't used `https` for the API feed.

`http` is disabled on android since a while back, unless you set up special security rules.

The rest of the time it's a CORS issue.

Comment: There is no CORS issue because I have faced this before and resolved it by using native HTTP call. I am going to try with https and will revert back to you.

Comment: yes it was an issue of https. Thank you for your help. App is working now.